# How to get the whole trace list of program with help of GDB?

Tags: gdb, trace

I want to get a whole trace list of my program "./myprog" - 
I have GDB 7.0-ubuntu (The newer version for my architecture doesn't exist).
My GDB-script ("./trace_list.gdb"):

```
gdb -q -x ./trace_list.gdb 


file ./myprog
set print address off
display/x $r0
display/x $r1
display/x $r2
display/x $r3
display/x $r4
display/x $r5
display/x $r6
display/x $r7
display/x $r8
display/x $r9
display/x $r10
display/x $r11
display/x $r12
display/x $sp
display/x $lr
display/x $fps
b *0x323d0
set logging on
run
while 1
x/i $pc
ni
end
quit
```

It works good for certain moment.
Then writes:

```
"./trace_list.gdb":26: Error in sourced command file:
Cannot access memory at address 0x6b980000
```

and doesn't execute further.

Why does this error occur?
What should I do to get the whole trace list of my program? May be I should use other tool? I haven't any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot access memory at address 0x6b980000
>   Why does this error occur?

The error means that GDB tried to access memory at `0x6b980000`, but couldn't (it told you that much ;-)

Most likely your target processor (which processor is it?) lacks hardware single-step (or GDB doesn't know how to use it), so in order to perform `ni`, GDB sets a temporary breakpoint on what it thinks is the next instruction. If GDB made a mistake, or if the instruction is in memory that GDB can't write to (e.g. part of kernel), you lose.

> What should I do to get the whole trace list of my program?

Whole trace is very rarely useful in practice -- there are just way too many instructions, and the overhead of single-stepping is too great. Perhaps you should abandon this approach, and use [divide-and-conquer debugging](http://books.google.com/books?id=jynA9ECbBsgC&pg=PA67&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) instead?

Update:

> "Whole trace is very rarely useful in practice" - even when the program is obfuscated?

Yes, especially if the program is obfuscated.

The program could be employing anti-debugging techniques as well. It is quite simple to make a program that behaves differently under debugger, and you may spend hours looking at whole trace that has nothing to do with actual program operation:

```
if (running_under_debugger()) {
  compute_one_million_digits_of_pi();
} else {
  do_something_useful();
}
```

Comment: "Whole trace is very rarely useful in practice" - even when the program is obfuscated?

Comment: It would be useful to get a trace of program between some breakpoints. But "Cannot access memory at address" each time enforces to break keyboards and throw monitors out of the window. P.S. The program is assembled statically (gcc --static) without any symbolic information.